# Creating a .jks from a .crt and .key file, is that possible

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, jks

I requested a SSL certificate from an authority.

First, I created a .csr and a .key file on my computer and saved those.  I sent the .csr and got back a .crt file and other files that I installed on my server.

All works fine for my Apache server with an SSL connection.  However, I would like to be able to use the same certificate for a Tomcat server that I also have running on the system on a different port (Using JIRA).  The setup needs a .jks file.  Is it possible to generate that from the files that I have?

This seems like it might work, but I don't have that utility in my CLASSPATH or cannot find it.

[Oracle instructions](https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/entry/steps_to_create_a_jks)

Comment: keytool sits in your %JAVA_HOME%\bin dir (unless your Java is older than 1.3) Use that. [some interesting blog post that answers your question](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)

Comment: I am familiar with key tool.  Just wasn't sure how to use it to do what I needed.  This seems to work:
[link](http://cunning.sharp.fm/2008/06/importing_private_keys_into_a.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert a PFX from those files:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.name.pfx -inkey domain.name.key -in domain.name.crt
```

Then export the jks from the PFX by following this guide:

https://blogs.oracle.com/blogbypuneeth/post/steps-to-create-a-jks-keystore-using-key-and-crt-files

Comment: That is actually what I did, and it worked, but thanks.

Answer (score 34):

You can use **openssl** and **keytool**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out domainname.pfx -inkey domainname.key -in domainname.crt -password pass:mypassword

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore domainname.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias 1 -srcstorepass mypassword -destkeystore domainname.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass mypassword -destalias myalias
```

Where

- domainname.crt is the **crt** *input file*
- domainname.key is the **key** *input file*
- domainname.pfx is the **pkcs12** intermediate file
- domainname.jks is the **jks** *output file*
- mypassword is the **password** of the pkcs12 and the jks files
- myalias is the **alias** of the certificate in the jks file