# Create jks from crt and key and than configure Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, https, jks, crt

I have received from my client *.crt, *.key and *.ca-bundle files and my environment use jre7.

I need to create *.jks file to configure Tomcat7.

I read this [Creating a .jks from a .crt and .key file, is that possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250271/creating-a-jks-from-a-crt-and-key-file-is-that-possible) but unfortunately at the end after this command

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\keystore\mykey.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias 1 -srcstorepass mypass -destkeystore C:\keystore\local.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass mypass -destalias myAlias
```

I receive the error

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: DER input not an octet string
```

How can I generate jks file and avoid that error?

After the jks file will be generated I will move it into ${TOMCAT_HOME}\conf folder.

Is this Tomcat configuration correct?

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
    maxThreads="200" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" 
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" keystoreFile="conf\local.jks" keystorePass="mypass" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not programming or development, but: are you using OpenSSL >= 3.0.0? If so it creates PKCS12 using 'modern' encryption (specifically PBES2/PBKDF2) that older Java did not handle; add `-legacy` to the `openssl pkcs12 -export` command. (Or if you want strong encryption on the certificates, which isn't really needed but some people like, make it `-legacy -descert`. Yes it's spelled `-descert` even though it actually does 3DES not DES.)

Comment: Yes, I used 3.1.3. If I try to add -legacy I receive this message : pkcs12: unable to load provider legacy
Hint: use -provider-path option or OPENSSL_MODULES environment variable.
F8210000:error:12800067:DSO support routines:win32_load:could not load the shared library:crypto\dso\dso_win32.c:108:filename(C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\lib\ossl-modules\legacy.dll)
F8210000:error:12800067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:crypto\dso\dso_lib.c:152:
F8210000:error:07880025:common libcrypto routines:provider_init:reason(524325):crypto\provider_core.c:904:name=legacy

Comment: Okay, your openssl build or install is broken. If you want to pursue that we would need details of the build, install, and possibly config, and I'm not sure SO is the right place. Alternatively it should work to not invoke the legacy logic but instead specify explicitly (but less conveniently) `-keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -macalg SHA1`.

Answer (score 0):

As @dave_thompson_085 said the problem was openssl version.
I installed 1.1.1 version, and then the jks it was correctly created.

To use the jks created in Tomcat use this configuration

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"  keyAlias="myalias" keystoreFile="conf\myalias.jks" 
    keystorePass="mypassword " keystoreType="JKS" maxThreads="200" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
    scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).